# One for the regex gurus

Tags: php, regex

This should be an easy one, but I'm tired and not thinking straight at the time.

I have the following string:

```
"Brian Hannah <brian@abktechnologies.com>"
```

I want to extract the name and email address into separate variables using PHP.

Comment: That's an entry level regex. For some tools that help with designing them read [Is there anything like RegexBuddy in the open source world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness, here's an approach using regular expressions:

```
preg_match('/^(.*)<(.*)>$/', $s, $matches);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Y000h)

Since the `*` is greedy in the first match, a string like `A<B <c.d>` will be parsed as `"A<B", "<c.d>"`, and not `"A", "<B <c.d>"`. To change this write `(.*?)` instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
Explode('<',$mystring).
```

If all strings are the same. Trim and remove >

Comment: [`split`](http://us3.php.net/split) is deprecated and should be avoided whenever possible...

Comment: What has it been replaced with?

Comment: @Toby: use [`preg_split`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).  `split()` is based on the EREG regex lib.  So since EREG is deprecated, `split` is as well.  Use either `preg_split` or (for this case particularly) just `explode`...

Comment: `explode`, it's functionally identical. Don't replace it with `preg_split` as then you load the whole regular expression engine again.

Comment: Actually I think explode is what I meant to use :) updated answer

Comment: @DanGrossman: `split` is functionally identical to `preg_split`.  The only difference is *which* regex engine is used (EREG vs PREG).  Explode uses straight string matches, so it's not functionally identical...

Comment: @ircmaxell From the [PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php): "preg_split(), which uses a Perl-compatible regular expression syntax, is often a faster alternative to split(). If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine."

Comment: Thanks all... seems I needed a Starbucks break and now it all seems so simple.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the PHP module [mailparse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) installed, you can use the [rfc822-parse-addresses](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-rfc822-parse-addresses.php)  function. There are also regex examples on that page, but they can't handle all the possible permutations. A full regex to decode email address runs to a couple of pages of densely packed regex.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the power (and CPU expense) of regular expressions for such simple string manipulation

```
$str = "Brian Hannah <brian@abktechnologies.com>";

$lt = strpos($str, '<');
$name = substr($str, 0, $lt - 1);
$email = substr($str, $lt + 1, strlen($str) - $lt - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically regular expressions are faster than PHP and its string functions. But a more basic approach would be:

```
strtok($string, "<")  and  $email = strtok(">");
```

Comment: The PHP manual says the opposite about performance on almost every string function...

Comment: @Dan: That's just true for the raw C function implementations. PHP bytecode runs slower than PCRE looks over strings. Not that it would make a blip in the profiler graphs for this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$v= "Brian Hannah <brian@abktechnologies.com>";

$arr = '#[<|>]#';

$d = preg_split($arr, $v);

var_dump( $d ) ;
```

Values will need to be trim()med tho

Comment: `[<|>]` also matches a `|` (inside a character class, `|` has no "special powers", so to say). Simply do `[<>]` to match either a `<` or a `>`.